# Filtering a numpy array using another array of labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter

Given two numpy arrays, i.e:

```
images.shape: (60000, 784) # An array containing 60000 images
labels.shape: (60000, 10)  # An array of labels for each image
```

Each row of `labels` contains a `1` at a particular index to indicate the class of the related example in `images`. (So `[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]` would indicate that the example belongs to Class 2 (assuming our class indexing starts from 0).

I am trying to efficiently separate `images` so that I can manipulate all images belonging to a particular class at once. The most obvious solution would be to use a `for` loop (as follows). However, I'm not sure how to filter `images` such that only those with the appropriate `labels` are returned.

```
for i in range(0, labels.shape[1]):
  class_images = # (?) Array containing all images that belong to class i
```

As an aside, I'm also wondering if there are even more efficient approaches that would eliminate the use of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to convert your label array to bool and use it for indexing:

```
classes = []
blabels = labels.astype(bool)
for i in range(10):
    classes.append(images[blabels[:, i], :])
```

Or as a one-liner using list comprehension:

```
classes = [images[l.astype(bool), :] for l in labels.T]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_classes= [[] for x in range(10)]
for image_index , element in enumerate(labels):
    _classes[element.index(1)].append(image_index)
```

for example the _classes[0] will contain the indexes of images which are classified as class0 .

Comment: if you are using numpy you can use 
     nonzero(element == 1)[0][0]
instead of element.index(1)